# Rails. Why does my submit button say Create vs. Update depending on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, text, submit

Be gentle to the newbie......

Ruby version 2.2.2p95, Rails version 4.2.1.

I completed the sample blog application. Works great, and I've been expanding on it. But I'm a noob, and clearly missing something fundamental. From the main index, you are presented with a listing of articles, and you have some links.

One link is to create a new article:

```
<%= link_to 'Post New Article', new_article_path %>
```

Another is to edit an existing article.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %>
```

In the first instance, the `new.html.erb` view is called up, and in the second, `edit.html.erb`. These files are identical, and render a partial `_form.html.erb`.

The forms are identical, but because you are following different paths, the resulting action is different. Fine, but why does the submit button show up in the browser as **Create Article** in one instance, and **Update Article** another? Where is that coming from? I'm using the same form to do 2 different things, what is causing the button to text to change?

Comment: can you post your `_form.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`?.

Comment: Rails 6 uses `@article.persisted?` to determine which text to use for the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in the **Rails Framework**. Whenever the new method is called the `params[:action] = 'new'`, So, for the `form` we use `f.submit`. This **f** object is the instance of that `new` method. Thus the framework decides to show the button name 'New Article'. `Article` is the **object** and **new** is the **action**.

For updating, the `params[:action]` is `edit`. But as we are using **PATCH/PUT** method for updating, rails show the button name `f.submit` = **Update Article**

Comment: This may have changed from the Rails version current when this answer was written, but in Rails 6 now, the decision is made based on `@article.persisted?`  ("Create" if false, "Update" if true)